# Suddenly getting "...'Layout' does not exist in current context" in _ViewStart.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a `MVC 3` project that I deployed about a year ago then moved on.

The client asked for some mods and I re-opened the solution to find the red squiggly line error in the `_ViewStart.cshtml` file.

I fixed the assembly `System.Web.MVC` version issue (3.0.0.0->3.0.0.1), but I have no idea why this is happening. I'm also getting the same red squiggly with `@RenderBody()` in the `_Layout_.cshtml` file.

Nothing has been changed and it compiled and ran fine last I looked. I suspect Windows update may be involved given the MVC assembly issue.

Oddly enough, when I create a brand new MVC 3 project, that project builds and deploys perfectly.

I'm using `VS2010` with `.NET 4.0.`

This is the only code in `_ViewStart.cshtml`:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/&#95;Layout&#95;.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: Did you fix this in both the main directory's web.config and the web.config in the /Views directory?

Comment: The only place I fixed the System.Web.MVC issue was by adding a new reference. I wasn't aware that I had to address the web.configs...(assuming you define 'fix this' as that issue).

Comment: Usually an assembly reference error remains after updating. You can usually fix that by adding an assembly binding redirect in the web.config. This is the one I use for MVC 5, for example.  You can change this to be from `0.0.0.0` to your exact version (`3.0.0.1`):  `
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and the error went away when I added the nuget package for Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc

Answer (score 0):

In my case I set **"Copy local" to false** for references in the project (I was trying something) to have only my DLLs in "bin" directory. So all "System.Web.*" binaries were missing (after cleanup).
So as I understand, you have to have MVC related binaries in your bin folder otherwise intellisense will not work properly..

VS 2019 Preview