# The name 'Layout' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013 that was recently update. The Mvc version as of now is 5.1. I am getting the error below:

[image]

I have tried the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060976/suddenly-getting-layout-does-not-exist-in-current-context-in-viewstart-c?rq=1), but its still showing me the same error. Below are the setting in the main web.config and /Views web.config respectively.

[image]

[image]

Please help, am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this located inside a plugin?

Comment: @JamesS no I have not used any plugins

Comment: @sumedha - I presume you have a reference to System.Web.WebPages in your main UI web project?

Comment: @Wheels73 yes its there

Comment: Are you sure `<add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />` exist in main web.config? I noticed that your main web.config doesn't have `<pages>` and `<namespaces>` element.

Answer (score 4):

I'm unsure if this is still an issue for you. I fixed my issue by closing the project, deleting the obj and bin folders,  and restarting it. I found the answer on here a while ago as I had the same issue but can't find it again to link you directly, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2017 you have to add

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

to the .csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I was writing like @model.Project_name.Models.Class_name
after removing the .(dot) before project_name my problem gets solved